# sharedPreferences is not working to between two fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences

fragment 1:

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sPrefs.edit();
editor.putString("name", "testnameJack");
editor.commit();
```

fragment 2:

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String data= sPrefs.getString("name", "err");
emailId.setText(data);
```

I want transfer data to between two fragment but not working

Comment: so data returns err?

Comment: Try to use simple way of fragment data transferring - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SharedPreferences sPrefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String data= sPrefs.getString("name","No name defined");
emailId.setText(data);
```

Comment: do you have a permission store in the device?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how it works. If you update `SharedPreferences` while both fragments are on screen... how would they know that the preference had changed. There are two ways to solve this easily:

1) Add an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to the preferences in the fragment you are attempting to update. When the listener detects a change you can alter your text. In your case fragment 2. for example:

```
sPrefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(
        new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            // .. Check the key to see if its the one you are looking for then set the text
          }
        });
```

Don't forget to unregister the listener to avoid leaks though.

2) Implement an interface in the parent `Activity` or `Fragment` and call a public method from the `Activity` in Fragment 2.

see [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Good Luck and Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

answer:

//Set Preference

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor;  
prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();  
//strVersionName->Any value to be stored  
prefsEditor.putString("STOREDVALUE", strVersionName);  
prefsEditor.commit();
```

//Get Preferenece

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs;    
myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);  
String StoredValue=myPrefs.getString("STOREDVALUE", "");
```

Thanks everyone :)